# перевести цикл в стрим

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Допустим, есть такой кусок кода:

```java
 public Set<Map<String, Object>> changeValues(String[] newValues, Set<Map<String, Object>> set) {
        for (String newValue : newValues) {
            String filterOperation = newValue.replaceAll("[^!=><%]", "");
            String filterColumnName = newValue.substring(0, newValue.indexOf(filterOperation)).trim();
            String filterColumnValue = newValue.substring(newValue.indexOf(filterOperation) + 1);
        }
```

Полученные данные я бы хотел обновить в `LinkedHasSet<Map<String,Object>>`.

На данный момент это выглядит примерно так:

```java
set.
stream().
filter(x->x.containsKey(filterColumnValue)).
forEach(x -> x.put(
    filterColumnName,
    ConverterClass.getConvertionMap().get(filterColumnName).apply(filterColumnValue)
));
```

Строка

```java
ConverterClass.getConvertionMap().get(filterColumnName).apply(filterColumnValue)
```

просто преобразует `filterColumnValue` из типа `String` к нужному типу (`Long`/`Double`), и кладет в виде `Object` в наш `set`.
Т.е по сути получается так:

```java
set.
stream().
filter(x->x.containsKey(filterColumnName)).
forEach(x -> x.put(filterColumnName, (Double/Long)filterColumnValue));
```

Весь код выглядит так:

```java
for (String newValue : newValues) {
    String filterOperation = newValue.replaceAll("[^!=><%]", "");
    String filterColumnName = newValue.substring(0, newValue.indexOf(filterOperation)).trim();
    String filterColumnValue = newValue.substring(newValue.indexOf(filterOperation) + 1).trim();

    set.forEach(x -> x.put(filterColumnName, (Double/Long)filterColumnValue));
}
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ перевести весь цикл и вставку данных в коллекцию `set` в один стрим?

Мой подход мне не нравится, ведь для каждого нового значения `newValue` мне придется по новому получать итератор (`set.forEach`), и мне кажется, что можно как-то все сделать при помощи стрима.

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас множество мап, и новую пару ключ-значение вы вставляете сразу во всех мапы множества? Тогда можно класть их в промежуточную мапу, а потом для `set` для каждого элемента сделать `putAll` из этой промежуточной мапы, вроде так уже меньше действий будет.

Comment: Откуда у вас берётся `set`?  Как вы получаете пару `имя-значение` при помощи представленного кода?

Comment: @NowhereMan изменил вопрос: set-один из аргументов метода. Мне необходимо в моем set обновить данные для ключа filterColumnName. Т.е для  ключа filterColumnName записать filterColumnValue. При помощи данного кода,я получаю стрим, который содержит в себе ключ filter(x->x.containsKey(filterColumnName),и меняю его значение

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть некая коллекция строк, которую можно *проще* преобразовать в коллекцию пар `имя=значение`, по сути в мапу, например так:

```java
Map<String, Object> map = newValues.stream()
    .map(str -> str.split("[!=><%]"))  // Stream<String[]>
    .map(arr -> new String[]{ arr[0].trim(), arr[1].trim()})
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        arr -> arr[0], // имя
        arr -> ConverterClass.getConvertionMap().get(arr[0]).apply(arr[1]),  // значение
        (v1, v2) -> v1,  // функция слияния на случай конфликтов
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

Здесь используется метод `String::split` для разбиения строки по делимитеру.

Затем для *заданного множества* `set` можно будет применить мапу с предыдущего шага как предложил @Byb в первом комментарии:

```java
set.forEach(m -> m.putAll(map));
```

Если нужно только *заменить* значения, существующие в мапах внутри `set`, можно использовать метод `Map::replaceAll`, в который нужно передать ссылку на метод в экземпляре новой мапы `map::getOrDefault`:

```java
// set.forEach(m -> m.replaceAll((k, v) -> map.getOrDefault(k, v)));
set.forEach(m -> m.replaceAll(map::getOrDefault));
```